# Consistent estimator. Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Z_i=\theta+\frac{X_i}{Y_i}$ where random vector $(X_i,Y_i)$ distributed uniformly in unit circle with center at $(0,0)$. I need to construct consistent estimator for parameter $\theta$ for sample $Z_1,..,Z_n$ I haven’t got an idea how to do this. The solution should Be logical in some sense. I believe that probability density function for this random vector is $\frac{1}{\pi}$ whenever my pair is  in the circle and zero else. So from this pdf I can evaluate pdf of $X$ and $Y$ by integrating. And I don’t know what should I do  after

Comment: Do you happen to know the distribution of the ratio $X_i/Y_i$?

Comment: If $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are vectors what do you mean by $\frac{X_i}{Y_i}$?

Comment: Actually no, I don’t know

Comment: I mean vector $(X_i,Y_i)$ it’s two coordinates $X_i$ and $Y_i$

Comment: Can't you just take the sample mean? The distribution for $\frac{X_{i}}{Y_{i}}$ should have either mean $0$ or undefined mean. So assuming the mean isn't undefined then sample mean should be enough.

Comment: @calcstudent When you actually do what you say, proving consistency turns out to hit a snag.  I think the best thing for the OP to do is to find out the distribution of the $X/Y$ ratio.

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO, is this a homework problem?

Comment: So it’s additional problem to my homework which I wanted to solve

Comment: OK, see my hint.

Comment: @passerby54, where is your hint

Comment: @kimchilover: I think the pdf for that distribution should be just $(\frac{1}{\pi(x^{2}+1)})$, which does show there is a problem, as neither mean nor variance are defined.

Comment: @calcstudent I was hoping Beesa would find that out, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W = (W_1,W_2) \sim N(0,I_2)$, that is, the two coordinates are independent $N(0,1)$. Then, $W / \|W\|$ is uniformly distributed *on* the unit circle. Multiplying by a proper scalar random variable $R$, we can make $R(W/\|W\|)$ uniformly distributed *in* the unit sphere. That is, $(X,Y)$ will have the same distribution as $R(W/\|W\|)$ and hence $X/Y$ will have the same distribution as
$$
\frac{RW_1/\|W\|}{R W_2/ \|W\|} = \frac{W_1}{W_2} \sim \text{??}(0,1)
$$
The ?? is a well-known distribution. So, you are dealing with a heavy tailed location family. A robust estimator of the mean, such as the median, can give you a consistent estimator. (There are other choices). You can try to prove the median is consistent. It would be for any continuous location family.

Comment: Heavy tailed you mean that it goes to zero slower? Can’t understand what is distribution which you marked with “??” Is it $N(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes, heavy-tailed means the pdf goes to zero slowly (much slower than N(0,1)). You can look up what the distribution of the ratio of two independent normal variables is.

Comment: The internet states that it is Cauchy distribution? But still I can’t see why coordinates $\sim N(0,1)$? And what is $I_2$?

Comment: See my argument in the post. What I am saying is X/Y has the same distribution as $W_1/W_2$ if the argument is correct. It really does not matter what distribution this is if you only want a consistent estimator. Just convince yourself that the noise has a continuous distribution, and show that the median is consistent for a such distribution.

Comment: Okay, what is noise? Sorry I’m not the native-speaker.

Comment: noise = X_i/Y_i.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try to refresh all of it in my head